# Right shift operator in java

Tags: java, scjp

```
public class Operator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte a = 5;
        int b = 10;
        int c = a >> 2 + b >> 2;
        System.out.print(c); //prints 0
    }
}
```

when 5 right shifted with 2 bits is 1 and 10 right shifted with 2 bits is 2 then adding the values will be 3 right? How come it prints 0 I am not able to understand even with debugging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This table provided in [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) will help you understand Operator Precedence in Java

```
additive    + -       /\  High Precedence
                      ||
shift   << >> >>>     ||  Lower Precedence
```

So your expression will be

```
a >> 2 + b >> 2;
a >> 12 >> 2;   // hence 0
```

Comment: So `int c = a >> (2+b) >> 2;` becomes `5 >> 12 >> 2`? then how do I evaluate it? 5 shifted with 12bits becomes zero? and then zero shifted with 2bits will result in zero. Is this correct?

Comment: @kittu-`All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated from left to right; assignment operators are evaluated right to left.` So, 5>>12 will be evaluated and then their result be calculated as (result >> 2).

Answer (score 2):

It's all about [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). Addition operator has more precedence over shift operators.

Your expression is same as:

```
int c = a >> (2 + b) >> 2;
```

Comment: Yeah that true but operator precedence will come in to play only after evaluation of operands right?

Comment: @kittu What do you mean by that? Expression `(2 + b)` will be evaluated first, and then the shift operations will be performed.

Comment: So `int c = a >> (2+b) >> 2;` becomes `5 >> 12 >> 2`? then how do I evaluate it?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
 int c = ((a >> 2) + b) >> 2;
```

You were shifting to the right by whatever is 2+b. I assume you wanted to shift 5 by 2 positions, right?

```
b000101 >> 2   ==   b0001øø
  | |___________________|_|
  |                     |
  |_____________________|
```

i.e. the leftmost bit shifts to the right by 2 positions and right most bit does as well (but is has no more valid positions left on its right side so it simply disappears) and the number becomes what's left - in this case '1'. If you shift number 5 by 12 positions you will get zero as 5 has less than 12 positions in binary form. In case of '5' you can shift by 2 positions at most if you want to preserve non-zero value.